# How to display data according to query string using ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multiple data & I want to display data as per query string, how can I do that in reactJs?

My code:

```js
const Ladies = () => {

  return (
      <div>
      if('http://localhost:3000/ladies?service=makeup'){
      <div>Makeup Content</div>
      }
      else('http://localhost:3000/ladies?service=hairStyling'){
      <div>Hair Styling Content</div>
      }      
      </div>
      )
      
}
```

Thank You!

Comment: You can use `const getQueryStringValue = (queryString) => {
        new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
        return urlParams.get(queryString);
      }` function to find out query string value and then generate the `div`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I consider this for your url

```
http://localhost:3000/ladies?service=makeup
```

In your code

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
```

check if it has the query

```
params.has('service')?params.get('service'):""
```

or log it

```
console.log(params.has('service')?params.get('service'):"")
```

return will be `makeup`

I'm not sure but i think it will be string so if you want to use it check if it's equal to "makeup" like so

```
<div> {params.has('service')&&params.get('service')==="makeup"?"There is makeup":"There is no make up in query strings !"}</div>
```

## Update:

you can put that just like a text to show a div instead, that is a great feature of jsx, do it like this.

```
<div>
  {params.has("service") && params.get("service") === "makeup" ? (
    <div>Makeup section</div>
  ) : params.get("service") === "hairStyling" ? (
    <div>hair styling section</div>
  ) : (
    <div>cannot find any query strings</div>
  )}
</div>
```

For more info check out [here](https://flaviocopes.com/urlsearchparams/)

Comment: Its working fine but there would be multiple condition how can i manage that?

Comment: I have to display DIV SECTION in conditions instead of just text...

Comment: Yahya parvar Thank you so much this is working fine now...